# How can we add list or multiple values for a single key in web.config in asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, web-config, key

How can we add list or multiple values for a single key in web.config?

For example: I have key named "xyz" it has a list of values, that is , val1, val2, val3 etc.

And this can be obtained in my code as other keys are accessible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add in web config as comma separated valued like

```
<add key = "xyz" value="val1, val2, val3"/>
```

access them as

```
  string[]  xyzValues = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xyz"].Split(",");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the appsettings tag

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="xyz" value="val1;val2;val3" />
</appSettings>
```

C# Code

```
string[] values = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xyz"].Split(';');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it directly but with a little more coding you may have custom config section in your config files. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx link  describes how to do custom config.

Other way could be use a separator in value and define multiple values and then use that values using split function(like other have mentioned)

Answer (score 1):

Define a separator character.

Then, get the application setting by its key and use `string.Split` to get those multiple values as an array or `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
IEnumerable<string> values = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xyz"].Split(',');
```