# XML Config File for Powershell, Storing a List

Tags: xml, powershell, iis

So I'm trying to stop a web-servers AppPools with Stop-AppPool.

I also want to run a config file that will allow me to exclude any appPools by name.

On my test webserver I have a config.xml file up and running that allows me to put a single AppPool name into a "Key" and then pull that later in Powershell. Specifically the applicable lines are:

Powershell:

```
[xml]$configFile = get-content D:\Test\WebsiteDeployConfig.xml
$excluded_AppPools = $configFile.configuration.appSettings.add.value
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <!--Vars -->
    <add key="apexclude" value="logging.mycompany.com"/>
    <!-- I would like to ALSO axclude "Manufacturer1_Akamai" -->
    <!--MoreVarsExample 
    <add key="var2" value="variableValue2"/>
    -->
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The issue here is when I start to try to add multiple AppPools to that "Exclude" list. I'm sure it's an XML skill thing but no formatting I try to add the second AppPool on seems to work.

Not only does the formatting not work but it seems anything I do to either that Key=apexclude xml line OR when I make another line, the page seems to no longer stop logging.mycompany.com.

So my question is, how do I add a second AppPool name to the config.xml file so I can exclude multiple sites?

I've Tried:

```
<add key="apexclude" value="logging.mycompany.com,Manufacturer1_Akamai"/>
```

```
<add key="apexclude" value="logging.mycompany.com;Manufacturer1_Akamai"/>
```

I've tried adding a new line to the working one with the same and with different key values

```
<add key="apexclude" value="logging.mycompany.com"/>
<add key="apexclude" value="Manufacturer1_Akamai"/>
```

I'm at a loss here. My best guess is I have to store them in an array, but I'm not sure how.

For Info: My Final Script is currently

```
import-module WebAdministration
import-module IISAdministration

[xml]$configFile = get-content D:\Test\WebsiteDeployConfig.xml
$excluded_AppPools = $configFile.configuration.appSettings.add.value
write-host 'the list of excluded AppPools is:'
write-host $configFile.configuration.appSettings.add.value

$sites = @(Get-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\* | where-object {$_.Name -ne $excluded_AppPools})
write-host "The Following Pools are Slated to Stop"
write-host $sites.Name

foreach ($site in $sites) {
    write-host "Stopping $_.Name"
    #Stop-WebAppPool -Name $site
    }
```

Comment: you could try <add key="mykey" value="A,B,C"/> string[] mykey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mykey"].Split(',');. refer this link fo rmore detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819964/multiple-values-for-a-single-config-key and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737620/how-can-we-add-list-or-multiple-values-for-a-single-key-in-web-config-in-asp-ne/32737753

Answer (score 0):

you could try

`<add key="mykey" value="A,B,C"/> string[] mykey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mykey"].Split(',');`

refer this link for more detail:

[Multiple values for a single config key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819964/multiple-values-for-a-single-config-key)

[How can we add list or multiple values for a single key in web.config in asp .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737620/how-can-we-add-list-or-multiple-values-for-a-single-key-in-web-config-in-asp-ne/32737753)